# unresolved external symbol, C++

Tags: c++, unresolved-external

I'm getting an error when trying to build a project regarding unresolved external symbols, however I can't find out where my issue lies, anyone got any ideas? thanks

Tball.cpp

```
#include "Tball.h"
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;



Tball::Tball(){

 Position = TVector(70,0,70);
 Verlocity = TVector(1,0,1);

}
```

Tball.h

```
#ifndef Tball_h
#define Tball_h

#include <iostream>
#include "mathex.h"
#include "tvector.h"


class Tball
{

public:

static TVector Position;
static TVector Verlocity;


Tball();
static void DrawBall(float x, float y, float z);
static TVector MoveBall();
static void init();
static int loadbitmap(char *filename);
static void SurfaceNormalVector();
static double Tball::collision();
static void Tball::pointz();



};


#endif
```

Error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Breakout Complete, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Tball.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>g:\work\second year\c++ breakout complete\breakout complete\tball.cpp(59): warning     C4715: 'Tball::MoveBall' : not all control paths return a value
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  Tvector.cpp
1>  TdisplayImp.cpp
1>  TBricks.cpp
1>Tball.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class     TVector     Tball::Verlocity" (?Verlocity@Tball@@2VTVector@@A)
1>Tball.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class     TVector     Tball::Position" (?Position@Tball@@2VTVector@@A)
1>G:\Work\Second year\C++ Breakout Complete\Debug\Breakout Complete.exe : fatal error     LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Nothing I've tried seems to work for me.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact errors please?  A note of the build command you use would be very handy too.

Comment: As an aside it's spelled 'Velocity' :)

Comment: haha I know, i realized after I'd created it and changing required far too much effort, while i was still trying to fix it

Comment: As another aside why is **everything** static. If everything is static there is no point in using classes at all. You should just write a bunch of functions. I have a sneaky suspicion that will solve your unresolved problem too.

Comment: When its not static, I get errors relating to 'non-static objects', my vector class works fine with statics, so I assumed this will

Comment: Your code works but the class itself is pointless. You might as well just write those as global functions and get rid of the Tball class. It has no purpose.

Comment: Well, the class may be used to encapsulated the functionality... The most pointless here is constructor. You may (and should) remove it - it will never get called, and if someone reads it later he could get confused by it :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this into your cpp:

```
TVector Tball::Position(/* contructor params */);
TVector Tball::Verlocity(/* contructor params */);
```

This make the "space" for these member static variables.

Comment: Where did you put the lines? Do not put them into contructor, but immediately after `using namespace std;` line.

Comment: Initial when i thought there was a problem I put them in the constructor, but now they after after using namespace std; it works great

Answer (score 2):

I dont see the definitions of

```
static TVector Position;
static TVector Verlocity;
```

This are the declarations only. You will need to define it, using some contructor (posible the default one) in one .ccp file. The static members are not part of each object and need to be created in a place other than an object constructor.

In your case:

Tball.cpp

```
#include "Tball.h"
#include <Windows.h>  // Why?
//using namespace std;    Why??


TVector Tball::Position(70,0,70);
TVector Tball::Verlocity(1,0,1);

Tball::Tball(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely (as there is no errors posted) you miss definition of

```
static TVector Position;
static TVector Verlocity;
```

To fix this add

```
Tball::Position(70,0,70);
Tball::Verlocity(1,0,1);
```

to your .cpp, and remove its initialization from constructor.

Comment: I think, it will complain about static keyword in definition.